# Unable to add an AlertDialog in the Tabbar app in android?

Tags: android, crash, tabbar, android-alertdialog

I have included tabbar for the android its working perfectly for Views but when I try for AlertDialogs the app seems to crash I have added the log cat.Kindly advice me on this on how to resolve this.Thanks

> 01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.CarBuyCo/com.CarBuyCo.Tabbed}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.CarBuyCo/com.CarBuyCo.TabGroup1Activity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.CarBuyCo/com.CarBuyCo.Scroller}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.CarBuyCo/com.CarBuyCo.TabGroup1Activity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.CarBuyCo/com.CarBuyCo.Scroller}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1491)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:657)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:329)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:219)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.CarBuyCo.Tabbed.addTab1(Tabbed.java:51)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.CarBuyCo.Tabbed.setTabs(Tabbed.java:31)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.CarBuyCo.Tabbed.onCreate(Tabbed.java:23)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  ... 11 more
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.CarBuyCo/com.CarBuyCo.Scroller}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1491)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.CarBuyCo.TabGroupActivity.startChildActivity(TabGroupActivity.java:61)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.CarBuyCo.TabGroup1Activity.onCreate(TabGroup1Activity.java:10)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  ... 22 more
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3536)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams.(AlertController.java:747)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.(AlertDialog.java:273)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.CarBuyCo.Scroller.makeAndShowDialogBox(Scroller.java:459)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.CarBuyCo.Scroller.(Scroller.java:33)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
>   01-08 04:14:21.575: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  ... 29 more

Comment: Thanks Preetha got it resolved myself...

Answer (score 0):

As the log says you cannot get system service before oncreate of the activity is called.
So move the getSystemService call to Oncreate or after.

Further you are trying to show the dialog box in constructor of scroller itself, and maybe you are instantiating Scroller as a field. Move the dialog box part to somewhere else